# Finding an input number to know where it should lie in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search

I have a small algorithm problem. I have an array for example.

```
array[10] = {23,54,10,63,52,36,41,7,20,22};
```

now given an input number for example 189 i want to know that in which slot it should lie.
 for example  this input should lie in 4 index in the array because

```
23+54+10+63 = 150 and if we add 52 then sum will be 202 which will cover the range where 189 should lie. so the answer should be 4.
```

I want to find an amortized constant time algorithm may be in the first step we do some prepossessing on the array so that all the next queries we can get in constant time.

The input number will always be in between 1 and sum of all the entries in array

Thanks

Comment: You won't be getting amortized constant time for either slot calculation or item insertion. as far as I can tell. Were you expecting to be able to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural solution would be to first build an array with the cumulative sums. This would look like

```
sums[10] = {23,77,87,...}
```

and then use a binary search such as the lower_bound algorithm to find where to insert. That would be `O(log(n))`. Assuming that your number of slots is constant, this solution is also time-constant. But I guess you want the lookup to be `O(1)` in terms of the number of slots. In this case, you will have to make a full lookup table. Since the size of these numbers is relatively small, that is perfectly doable:

```
int lookup[N];
for(i=0,j=0;i<10;i++)
    for(k=0;k<sums[i];k++,j++)
        lookup[j]=i;
```

Using this, the slot number is simply `lookup[number]`.

Comment: In a slight modification of this, you could instead have an array containing the same number of elements as the sum total of all the values in the array (in this case, 328). The value of each item in the array corresponds to the array slot... `lookup[189]` and `lookup[200]` would both have a value of `4`, for example. This will be sharply limited by the sum of the values in the array, however... but for the OP's example it would work as an O(1) lookup easily enough.

Comment: @Rook: I think that is exactly what I did here.

Comment: Huh. I could have sworn than the second part of your answer wasn't there when I was typing in my reply... just as much as the `O(log(b))` statement. Possibly I'm going mad.

Comment: i think most of the people are right about O(logn) time algorithm. For constant time i need a lot more memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need constant time, create a second array that has a size that is the largest sum value that contains indexes into the original array. So new_array[189] = 4;

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can get is to use the cumulative array and run in logarithmic time by using binary search. I am not sure if a solution with constant time is existing. Are you sure there is one?

Comment: i am not sure if there exists one. But i am really interested if there is that's why asked with the community members.

Comment: I think it does not exist. Because you will have an array of values with "holes" and you will need to search in this array to find your place. And this search cannot be done in O(1)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the number is always between 1 and the sum of all items in the array, then the trivial constant time algorithm is to build an array of [1..sum], each entry containing the proper slot for each number. Building the array, which you only have to do once, is O(N). Lookup is then O(1).

This assumes, of course, that you have enough memory for the array.

Other than that, I think the best you'll be able to do is O(log(N)) using binary search on the sums.

Answer (score 0):

assuming

> The input number will always be in between 1 and sum of all the
>   entries in array

```
int total(0), i(0);
for(;total < inputValue; ++i)
{
    total += array[i];
}
//your answer is i-1
```

Comment: Whereas that works, the running time is dependent on the number. He's looking for a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: @jim it crossed my mind to add "int answer(i);for(;i<10;++i){total+=array[i];}" at the end just to make it run in constant time :P